# Is there a simple way to forward to a member function with a matching function signature?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Is there a simple way to forward to a member function with a matching function signature?

```
typedef std::tr1::function<int(int,int,int,int)> TheFn;
class C
{
    int MemberFn(int,int,int,int) { return 0; }

    TheFn getFn() { 
        //is there a simpler way to write the following line?
        return [this](int a,int b,int c,int d){ return this->MemberFn(a,b,c,d); };
    } 
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could get some insight by looking at how std::mem_fun is implemented?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're really trying to accomplish here. I don't think what you've asked (per se) is possible, but it's close enough that I suspect the underlying problem can still be solved once we know what it is.

Comment: In my application, I have hundreds of 'smart communication blocks' that are initialized with a optional setters and getters. Most of the time these are just fowarded to a member function with the same signature on a particular object. I was hoping for something like MagicBind( this, &MemberFn ). I was just trying to reduce code noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `bind`?

```
// C++0x update
struct test {
   void f( int, int, int, int );
};
int main()
{
   std::function<void (int,int,int,int)> fn;
   test t;
   fn = std::bind( &t::f, &t, 
           std::placeholders::_1, 
           std::placeholders::_2, 
           std::placeholders::_3, 
           std::placeholders::_4 );
   fn( 1, 2, 3, 4 ); // t.f( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
}
```

I have left the full qualification of all elements, but `std::placeholders` applied so many times don't really help readability... I guess a `using std::placeholders` would not hurt at all:

```
using std::placeholders;
fn = std::bind( &t::f, &t, _1, _2, _3, _4 );
```

EDIT: To make it closer to the question code, so that it is clearer that this has the exact same functionality that the original code:

```
typedef std::function<int(int,int,int,int)> TheFn;
class C {
   int MemberFn( int, int, int, int ) { return 0; }
public:
   int MemberFn2(int,int,int,int) { return 2; }
   TheFn getFn() {
      using std::placeholders;
      return std::bind( &C::MemberFn, this, _1, _2, _3, _4 );
   }
};
int main() {
   C instance;
   TheFn fn1 = instance.getFn();
   std::cout << fn1( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) << std::endl; // 0

   using std::placeholders;
   TheFn fn2 = std::bind( &C::MemberFn2, &instance, _1, _2, _3, _4 );
   std::cout << fn2( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see in both cases you are doing the same. I have used private and public methods for the example to show that when you `bind`, the member method access level is checked at the place of bind, not at the place of call. So even if `MemberFn` is private within the class you can call it through the binded functor. If the member is public, you can actually bind from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to make something out of Boost::Lambda, but in reality, I'd suggest not, except that you may find it easier to use a trailing return type than explicitly typedef. In addition, as far as I know, when you capture this, as a special case, then the lambda becomes a member lambda, as it were, and you don't need the explicit this->.